# line break in notepad with coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, coldfusion-9

I cannot convince why I cannot break line in notepad with coldfusion.

Here is my coding

```
<cfscript>
    msg = "ppshein<CR>Coldfusion Developer<CR>Currently working in Singapore";
    currentPath = getCurrentTemplatePath();
    currentDirectory = getDirectoryFromPath(currentPath);
    chgMsg = ReReplace(msg, "<CR>", "<CR>\r\n", "ALL");
    FileWrite("#currentDirectory#\myfile.txt", "#chgMsg#");
    return "successfully generated";
</cfscript>
```

what I run above coding and open myfile.txt, it happen so

```
ppshein<CR>Coldfusion Developer<CR>Currently working in Singapore
```

What I want is

```
ppshein<CR>
Coldfusion Developer<CR>
Currently working in Singapore
```

Any comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think you need ReReplace here, plus your replacement string is incorrect -- CF does not recognize this format. Try this one:

```
chgMsg = Replace(msg, "<CR>", chr(13)&chr(10), "ALL");
```

UPD. Let me try to optimize whole block of code a bit...

```
<cfscript>
    msg = "ppshein<CR>Coldfusion Developer<CR>Currently working in Singapore";
    chgMsg = Replace(msg, "<CR>", chr(13)&chr(10), "ALL");
    FileWrite(ExpandPath("./myfile.txt"), chgMsg);
    return "successfully generated";
</cfscript>
```

A bit more clean and easy to read.

Comment: Gosh..!! Right. I've gave the wrong code. Actual code is as follow.

chgMsg = Replace(msg, "<CR>", "<CR>" & chr(13), "ALL");

I've forgot to put chr(10) after chr(13). Thanks for your time.